# Unable to create new angular project err code EINTEGRITY

Tags: npm, command-line-interface

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY

### npm ERR! sha512-SO5lYHA3vO6gz66erVvedSCkp7AKWdv6VcQ2N4ysXfPxdAlxAMMAdwegGGcv1Bqwm7naF1hNdk5d6AAIEHV2nQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-SO5lYHA3vO6gz66erVvedSCkp7AKWdv6VcQ2N4ysXfPxdAlxAMMAdwegGGcv1Bqwm7naF1hNdk5d6AAIEHV2nQ== but got sha512-LXTuXDSXhBa0m5dqYlkGlQixZUszprAyBVeoa96dsxK93J9w2+Btw0VSiOnbhzhImI8v4xuIBy5ZKaH8hTAtIQ==. (5075 bytes)

Got the following error....

Answer (score 0):

This issue actually is not related to the Angular. So, I've removed the angular tag.

This is an NPM issue and there can be a number of reasons for the same.

If you are on Linus, execute the following commands as an SU.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
rm -rf ~/.npm
npm install --update-binary --no-shrinkwrap
```

If you are on windows, perform following,

```
remove node_modules directory
remove package-lock.json file
remove -rf ~/.npm file
npm install --update-binary --no-shrinkwrap
```

Comment: i am on windows.....i dont know from which folder i have to remove node_modules directory...

Comment: it should be in your windows directory's program files folder

Comment: check npm or nodejs

Comment: I have node_modules folder in the nodejs folder.... Do i have to remove this? ... There is no package-lock.json file

Comment: search for both the files in the explorer's search